# Understanding Bilinear Layers

Tags: python, matrix, neural-network, linear-algebra, pytorch

When having a bilinear layer in PyTorch I can't wrap my head around how the calculation is done.

Here is a small example where I tried to figure out how it works:

**In:**

```
import torch.nn as nn
B = nn.Bilinear(2, 2, 1)
print(B.weight)
```

***Out:***

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([[[-0.4394, -0.4920],
         [ 0.6137,  0.4174]]], requires_grad=True)
```

---

I am putting through a zero-vector and a one-vector.

**In:**

```
print(B(torch.ones(2), torch.zeros(2)))
print(B(torch.zeros(2), torch.ones(2)))
```

***Out:***

```
tensor([0.2175], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
tensor([0.2175], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
```

I tried adding up the weights in various ways but I'm not getting the same result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The operation done by `nn.Bilinear` is `B(x1, x2) = x1*A*x2 + b` (c.f. [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Bilinear)) with:

- `A` stored in `nn.Bilinear.weight`
- `b` stored in `nn.Bilinear.bias`

If you take into account the (optional) bias, you should obtain the expected results.

---

```python
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

def manual_bilinear(x1, x2, A, b):
    return torch.mm(x1, torch.mm(A, x2)) + b

x_ones = torch.ones(2)
x_zeros = torch.zeros(2)

# ---------------------------
# With Bias:

B = nn.Bilinear(2, 2, 1)
A = B.weight
print(B.bias)
# > tensor([-0.6748], requires_grad=True)
b = B.bias

print(B(x_ones, x_zeros))
# > tensor([-0.6748], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
print(manual_bilinear(x_ones.view(1, 2), x_zeros.view(2, 1), A.squeeze(), b))
# > tensor([[-0.6748]], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)

print(B(x_ones, x_ones))
# > tensor([-1.7684], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
print(manual_bilinear(x_ones.view(1, 2), x_ones.view(2, 1), A.squeeze(), b))
# > tensor([[-1.7684]], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)

# ---------------------------
# Without Bias:

B = nn.Bilinear(2, 2, 1, bias=False)
A = B.weight
print(B.bias)
# None
b = torch.zeros(1)

print(B(x_ones, x_zeros))
# > tensor([0.], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
print(manual_bilinear(x_ones.view(1, 2), x_zeros.view(2, 1), A.squeeze(), b))
# > tensor([0.], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)

print(B(x_ones, x_ones))
# > tensor([-0.7897], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
print(manual_bilinear(x_ones.view(1, 2), x_ones.view(2, 1), A.squeeze(), b))
# > tensor([[-0.7897]], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
```

Comment: Thats it! In formulas for bilinear forms I there wasn't any bias - but of course the layer adds a bias. Thank you! :)